# How to access cookies in private mode in Selenium/Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I need to be able to access cookies while running Firefox in private mode through geckodriver and Selenium. Currently when I have simple check if value exists in a cookie it fails when I add "-private" option. Works fine without it. I have the latest version of Firefox/geckodriver installed at the time of writing this question.

Comment: Selenium already runs browsers in Private mode

Comment: If it did then SSO of the current user wouldn't work. But it does.

Comment: Without seeing the code it is difficult to correctly identify the problem.